# ion-autocomplete not displaying results case-sensitive

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic and using ion-autocomplete to display my list of items.
if i have my result array like this

```
var homeworksingle = [
{id: '1', name: 'Maths'}, 
{id: '2', name: 'English'},
{id: '3', name: 'Physics'}
];

<input ion-autocomplete type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ion-autocomplete" autocomplete="off" ng-model="model" item-value-key="id" item-view-value-key="name" items-method="getTestItems(query)" items-method-value-key="items" placeholder="Enter test query ..." items-clicked-method="itemsClicked(callback)" items-removed-method="itemsRemoved(callback)"/>

$scope.getTestItems = function (query) {
    var homeworksingle = [
            {id: '1', name: 'Maths'}, 
            {id: '2', name: 'English'},
            {id: '3', name: 'Physics'}
        ];

    var returnValue = { items: [] };
    homeworksingle.forEach(function(item){
        if (item.name.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
            returnValue.items.push(item);
        }
        else if (item.id.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
            returnValue.items.push(item);
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
```

};

and when i try to search my list nd input 'm', it returns no result but when i input 'M' it returns data.

How do i set it to also acknowledge or search when input is lowercase or uppercase.

Thanks